# Php check a specific pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to check a certain pattern in a string. My pattern contains 3 parts:

- Start : First character should be a number or alphabet
- End : Last character should be a number or alphabet
- Middle : In between characters can be any combination of numbers, alphabets or a hyphen/minus(-) or @.

I am using following regex:

> preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i');

and tested on string :

> a-121kabrastreet@90

which evaluates to false. Please rectify my logic.
Thank you

Comment: `/a-zA-Z/i` - it must be ignore-case-twice day. I see three conditions in your "text requirements, and three repetitions in your pattern. Please put "the middle repeated pattern" `[@\-]*` in words. How is the string "aa" matched, how "aaa"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alphabets and digits should also be added to the character class in the middle. Note that you don't have to escape the hyphen if it is places at the end of the character class.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][@a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

You use the case insensitive flag, your pattern could look like:

```
/^[a-z0-9][@a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$/i
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/srWvsQ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/7AFnC)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It works. How can i add backward slash(\\) to it. I tried this : /^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9@\-\/\\\]*[a-z0-9]+$/i and tested with : a-121k/ab/rast@ree-t@9\0, which gives false

Comment: There is also a backslash in there, try https://regex101.com/r/srWvsQ/2